# How can I increase the default ringing time on a phone using asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have an asterisk pbx setup on my server. We call to phone numbers using our pbx asterisk 11. The default ringing time on the phone numbers seems to be very low around 20 seconds. Is there any way in asterisk to increase the ringing time, if yes then please let me know how can I do this.

Regards

Comment: What's the ring-timeout used in the Dialplan of Dial Commands, eg. `exten => s,1,Dial(IAX2/user:pass@otherend.com/500,ring-timeout)` ? If no ring-timeout is specified, the channel will ring indefinitely.

Comment: Based on the Asterisk 11 documentation:
```timeout - Specifies the number of seconds we attempt to dial the specified devices.
If not specified, this defaults to 136 years.```

Answer (score 5):

Asterisk 11 - Dial options

You are referring to the **timeout** of the **Dial** application. It is easy to fix, just include after a coma the number of seconds that you want to ring.

Example: `exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/1000,60)`
This example will ring extension 1000 during 60 seconds.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Dial+Application

But, maybe you are using somekind of frontend, like FreePBX, Elastix, etc. Whit this frontends, your configuration is scripted to the previous code, so, this parameter must be configurable.

Look for dialing options, you will find something like **default dial timeout**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why do we need to add everything to an extension, isn't there a global variable for this?

Comment: Not really sure, as far as I know, no, there isn't. But you can define your very own variable on the context (or in a global context) and use it here.
`Set(name=value)`

Most of the frontend and GUIs work with this _custom variable_ idea